# binding is not working on table for sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I created xml view and controller to bind data.
I don't see any data.
Did I miss something?

```
<sap.ui.core.mvc:View controllerName="view.weeklyTasks"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:sap.ui.core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:sap.ui.core.mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <Page title="Title">
    <content>
      <Table id="idProductsTable" noDataText="No data" items="{path: '/modelData'}" >
        <columns>
          <Column>
            <Text text="Product" />
          </Column>
          <Column>
            <Text text="Supplier" />
          </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
          <ColumnListItem counter="0">
            <cells>
              <Text text="{name}"></Text>
              <Text text="{date}"></Text>
            </cells>
          </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
        <headerToolbar>
          <Toolbar>
            <content>
              <Label text="Weekly Tasks"></Label>
            </content>
          </Toolbar>
        </headerToolbar>
      </Table>
    </content>
  </Page>
</sap.ui.core.mvc:View>

sap.ui.controller("view.weeklyTasks", {
  onInit: function() {

    var aData = { modelData : [ 
      {name: "Peter",  date: "01012010"},
      {name: "Petra",  date: "01012011"},
      {name: "Thomas", date: "01012012"},
      {name: "John",   date: "01012013"},
      {name: "Maria",  date: "01012014"}
    ]};



    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(aData);
    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your code but I couldn't find a complete solution yet. However, I could see that your JSON is not valid. You have to include double quotes on "modelData", "name" and "date".

You can use the following link to validate a JSON
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok now I could make things work.

**1 - Add the parameter below to your bootstap**

```
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
```

More info regarding data-sap-ui-xx-binding Syntax:

[Data Modeling for controls using XML views(SAPUI5)](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3540813)

[SAP Help - SAPUI5 Configuration Options](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm?frameset=/en/91/f08de06f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/e4/843b8c3d05411c83f58033bac7f072/plain.htm&node_id=265)

**2 - Your view is OK**

```
<Page title="Title">
  <content>
    <Table id="idProductsTable" noDataText="No data" items="{path: '/modelData'}" >
      <columns>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Product" />
        </Column>

        <Column>
          <Text text="Supplier" />
        </Column>
      </columns>

      <items>
        <ColumnListItem >
          <cells>    
            <Text text="{name}"></Text>
            <Text text="{date}"></Text>
          </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
      </items>
    </Table>
  </content>  
</Page>
```

**3 - Update your controller fixing JSON format**

```
onInit: function() {

  var aData = { "modelData" : [ 

    {"name": "Peter",  "date": "01012010"},
    {"name": "Petra",  "date": "01012011"},
    {"name": "Thomas", "date": "01012012"},
    {"name": "John",   "date": "01012013"},
    {"name": "Maria",  "date": "01012014"}
  ]};

  var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(aData);

  this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  // OR sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);  
}
```

Comment: `data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"` was what i was missing. Works now. Thanks

Comment: `data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge` also does the job

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to bind the items property in the controller so it can change dynamically, how would I go about doing this?

I imagine it would be something like `oTable.items = "{odataURL}"`

My URL current works if hardcoded in, but I am not sure how I could get the same results doing this in the controller.js

Answer (score 0):

```
As per Question asked there is no need to make change in JSON  format .
Normally we use Complex Binding when we have formatter/sorter or path added  
we can achieve above result in other way also 
just remove **path** from item and remove **data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"** in     index.html 

<Table id="idProductsTable" noDataText="No data" items="{/modelData}">
      <columns>
        <Column>
          <Text text="Product" />
        </Column>

        <Column>
          <Text text="Supplier" />
        </Column>
      </columns>

      <items>
        <ColumnListItem >
          <cells>    
            <Text text="{name}"></Text>
            <Text text="{date}"></Text>
          </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
      </items>
    </Table>
```